# Openshift - multiple auth providers

Tags: openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

Does openshift (Origin or Enterprise) support multiple auth providers ? 
eg 1. htpasswd (if not found ) 2. ldap 
[This link talks about various auth supported but can we use multiple](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/install_config/configuring_authentication.html)

```
    ...
oauthConfig:
  identityProviders:
  - name: htpasswd_auth
    challenge: true
    login: false
    mappingMethod: "claim"
...
  - name: "my_ldap_provider" 
    challenge: true 
    login: true 
    mappingMethod: claim 
    provider:
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify multiple auth providers.  Just make sure they have different names.  You'll also want to be careful cases where their preferred usernames will collide.  `claim` (like you have it) is a pretty safe default.  See https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#mapping-identities-to-users if you want to read up on alternatives.